# Write data in JSON file, send JSON file from client to server, read JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I have a client/server application, the Client is an Android Application developed with Android Studio and and Server is a classic Java Application.

Here the screens of interested parts:

Client:

[image]

Server:

[image]

Now what i need is that when i click on button "RICHIEDI" in android application (client), the fields Nome and Cognome gone write on a JSON file and this JSON sent to server and then the Nome and Cognome shows in the two jtextfield of the server application, how can i do it? can you help me?

Comment: This is a very long answer. But I can direct you to the right way, rest is yours to figure it out. Create a class with nome and cognome fields in it. Initialize your class with the values you get from your edittext field. Use Gson to create your json from your class instance. Then use a http library like volley or okhttp etc. to send that body to your server.

Answer (score -1):

Make your json object in http://jsonschema2pojo.org/ from here, then send to your server, handle the response like this as well